# How can I force vis.js edges in a rendered DAG to "jump" graph levels?

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I have used vis.js to draw some DAGs using the hierarchical layout option. It works well, however for my use case there are often going to be edges that must "jump vertex generations," not certain if I am saying that properly. Essentially, one branch may have 10 levels, and then a sibling of the parent of the deep branch may want to connect to the deepest leaf node.

This "works" - vis.js draws it. But it screws up my layout, shifting a large portion of the preexisting graph, and it will not be useful for a user to look at the result. I have attached a picture of what I am trying to achieve and what the current results are, can anyone point me in the right direction?[image: DAG layout problem]

Comment: putting together the graphic above was enough to spur me into realizing that vis.js lets you set node levels on a per-node basis, and respects them quite well. I just have to manually calculate each node's level based on my ordering (date, and some other considerations). To the mods: this can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution turned out to be very simple, I just overlooked it. Using the hierarchical layout, it is possible to assign each `node` a field called `level`. It is an all-or-nothing option: either you let vis.js take care of the levels, or you manually assign all your nodes a `level`. It respects the levels very well, and when adding edges to nodes whose levels have been manually defined, the nodes no longer jump around the layout.